# sortable jquery don't show the variable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this code:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
axis: 'x',
handle: '.fancybox',
update: function() {
    debugger;
    var order = $('#sortable').sortable('serialize');
    alert(order);
}
});
```

But it doesn't show anything in the alert function.
How can I get this order var and sent it to php with ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that your li elements have an id and include an underscore (e.g. `_1` and so on).

jQuery UI demo: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-serialize

My demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YkuGQ/